# Функция Like работает неправильно

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

Есть функция Like

```
public ActionResult LikeMethod(string userId, int postId)
        {
            var userLike = _context.Publications.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == postId);
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (userLike != null)
                {
                    userLike.Like = userLike.Like + 1;

                    _context.Update(userLike);
                    _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                }
            }

            return View();
        }
```

так же есть js скрипт

```
<script>
    function sendLike(userId, postId) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("LikeMethod", "Publications")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { 'postId': postId, 'userId': userId },
            success: function(data) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                        alert('Вы поставили Like!', data)
                    },
                    500);
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log('Ошибка во время отправки комментария', this);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Так выглядит Html кнопки.

```
<div id="postdiv-@Model.Id">
    <form>
        <input id="LikeId" type="button" value="Like" class="btn btn-default" onclick="sendLike('@Model.UserId', '@Model.Id')"
               style="color: aliceblue; background-color: darksalmon;" />
    </form>

</div>
```

Проблема в следующем:

Когда добавляешь лайк он ставиться не сразу, приходиться 
обновлять страницу по несколько раз.
Так же может и не с первого раза ставить лайк,
приходиться по несколько раз ставить и обновлять страницу, 
что бы заработал. В чём может быть причина?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь сохранять асинхронно (`_context.SaveChangesAsync();`) в синхронном методе, то есть метод возвращает управление ещё до того, как сохранение в БД произошло.

Comment: @tym32167 Работает! Спасибо!!! А, можно как то сделать что бы страница сама обновлялась. Всё равно приходиться обновить страницу , что бы изменения вступили в силу.

Comment: в таких случаях есть 2 подхода: 1) Обновлять всю страницу, чтобы увидеть результат 2) Обновлять только часть страницы, где данные были изменены. Первое сделать просто, но тогда смысл использования ajax теряется. Второе сделать сложнее, но тоже можно. Выберите что вам из этого надо, попытайтесь сами решить проблему, если не получится - задайте это отдельным вопросом.

Comment: @tym32167 Ок! Спасибо! Поищу решение!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь сохранять асинхронно (`_context.SaveChangesAsync();`) в синхронном методе, то есть метод возвращает управление ещё до того, как сохранение в БД произошло. Либо сохраняйте синхронно

```
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Либо асинхронно

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> LikeMethod(string userId, int postId) // изменение здесь
    {
        var userLike = _context.Publications.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == postId);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (userLike != null)
            {
                userLike.Like = userLike.Like + 1;
                _context.Update(userLike);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); // и здесь
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```